# Error in templated "find-and-erase" function

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator

```
template <typename CONTAINER_TYPE, typename CONTAINER_VALUE_TYPE>
bool FindAndErase(CONTAINER_TYPE& cont, const CONTAINER_VALUE_TYPE& value)
{
    CONTAINER_TYPE::iterator it = eastl::find(cont.begin(), cont.end(), value);
    if (it != cont.end())
    {
        cont.erase(it);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This code compiles fine on Visual C++ 2005, but compiling using an ARM compiler ("ARM C/C++ Compiler, RVCT4.0") and the iOS gcc ("arm-apple-darwin9-gcc (GCC) 4.2.1") returns errors:

Error:  #65: expected a ";"
Error:  #20: identifier "it" is undefined

in the 4th and 5th lines respectively.

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try

```
typename CONTAINER_TYPE::iterator it ...
```

Comment: No offense, but I don't see how this got 9 upvotes while Nawaz's answer, which provides an explanation & alternative got only 5...

Comment: @LuchianGrigore me neither ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Use `typename` as:

```
typename CONTAINER_TYPE::iterator it = //...
```

Because `iterator` is a *dependent* name and you need to tell the compiler that what follows is a *type*, not *static value*.

In C++11, you could just use `auto` as:

```
auto it = eastl::find(cont.begin(), cont.end(), value);
```

What a relief!

Answer (score 3):

**Dependent names**. MSVS doesn't treat this as an error. You need an extra `typename` there:

```
typename CONTAINER_TYPE::iterator it = eastl::find(cont.begin(), cont.end(), value);
```